# Can you push a file to the emulator using eclipse run configuration?

Tags: eclipse, android-emulator, run-configuration

Basically I'm doing some database work and I need to push a clean copy of the database to the emulator before each launch.  Doing this from DDMS before every run is getting a bit tedious so I'm trying to figure out a way to include it in the run configuration.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the `Android-SDK\platform-tools` folder, there is the `adb.exe` program that you can use from the command line to push the files to the AVD.

Example: `adb push [filename] [targetlocation]`

Comment: I'm not having trouble pushing the files to the emulator.  I'm trying to find a way to have them pushed automatically in the run configuration.